# Array splice removes the wrong element in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I read all the other questions by others and answers, but still can't figure it out..

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-striped" ng-show="coffees.length>0">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Drink</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Number per week</th>
                    <th></th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr ng-repeat="c in coffees">
                    <td>{{c.type}}</td>
                    <td>{{c.price | currency:"&pound;"}}</td>
                    <td>{{c.numberpw}}</td>
                    <td><a href ng-click="removeCoffee($index)">X</a></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module("calculator",[]);

app.controller('pageController',function($scope){       
    $scope.coffees=[];  
});

app.controller('coffeeController',function($scope){     

    $scope.addCoffee=function(coffee){      
        $scope.coffees.push(coffee);
        $scope.coffee={};
    }

    $scope.removeCoffee=function(el){       
        $scope.coffees.splice($scope.coffees[el],1);
    }
});
```

coffeeController is nested within pageController, so I can access $scope.coffees inside the coffeeController. And addCoffee function accepts an object that looks like this:

```
<select name="CoffeeType" ng-model="coffee.type" ng-options="type for type in 
['Espresso','Latte']" class="form-control" required>
<option value="">Please select</option>
</select>                      

<input type="text" placeholder="&pound;00.00" ng-pattern="/^0|[1-9][0-9]*$/" ng-model="coffee.price" name="CoffeePrice" class="form-control" required />

<select name="NumberPerWeek" class="form-control" ng-model="coffee.numberpw" ng-options="n for n in [1,2,3,4,5]" required>
<option value="">Please select</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-left" value="Add Drink" ng-click="addCoffee(coffee)" />
```

It adds objects perfectly but removes the wrong object every single time..

Comment: Can you put your code on plunker?

Comment: are you sure it is not index prob? which object is removed, one before the index ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`splice` expects start/count integers. `$scope.coffees[el]` is an object but you're passing in the `$index` to the method. Update your remove method as follows:

```
$scope.removeCoffee=function(el){       
    $scope.coffees.splice(el,1);
}
```